# line 929 xstring assert invalid null pointer

Tags: c++

when I debug on visual studio it will run but when I run the .exe I receive the following error:

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring 
Line 929 
Expression: Invalid Null pointer

this is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>   //For access
#include <sys/types.h>  //For stat().
#include <sys/stat.h>  //For stat(). 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[]){

    string* argument = new string();
    string strPath = argv[1];
    argument = nullptr;
    argument = &strPath;

    if ( access( strPath.c_str(), 0 ) == 0 ){

        struct stat status;
        stat( strPath.c_str(), &status );

        if ( status.st_mode & S_IFDIR ){
            cout << "The directory exist." << endl;  
            getc(stdin);
        }
    }
    else{
        mkdir( "C:\\Program Files\\EZshred\\" );      
        getc( stdin );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I  tried everything but I don't know what else to do please help

Comment: Remove code, recompile, run; if it still fails, repeat. First recommendations: get rid of that thrashing around with `argument`; it's never used. Second, get rid of most of those `#inlude` directives; they're mostly pointless here. Then start cutting back further.

Comment: It might be a good idea to check if you even have a `argv[1]` before you go dereferencing it... And what's the purpose of your `argument` variable, which you create a new `string` to assign to it, and then throw it away and assign it something else that you never use again?

Comment: @PeteBecker what do you mean with "thrashing" and also I cant get rid of some of those #include because im going to use those for other purposes inside this program.

Comment: @twalberg I have the argv[1] which is the path for the directory im looking for

Comment: @twalberg ok thanks I fixed that problem but now I have another one "Line 80" access.c "path != NULL"

Comment: The code assign a value to `argument`, overwrites that value with a NULL pointer, and overwrites that with another value, then doesn't use it. Most of those headers aren't needed **for this example**; you can remove them without affecting **this example**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some updated code. Since you never really use `strPath` except as `strPath.c_str()`, there's not really any reason to wrap it in a `string`. Sure `string` is better for general use if you are going to be parsing or splitting or adding to it or whatever, but in this case, it's really not necessary. Also got rid of `argument`, since it doesn't seem necessary. Furthermore, you were calling `access()` questionably, with a second argument of zero. `F_OK` happens to be defined as zero on Linux systems, but I'm not sure it's guaranteed to be so everywhere. In addition, since you're using `_tmain()`, it's probably wise to use `_TCHAR* argv[]` as well, especially if you're building a Unicode or other wide-char project (although I'm far from authoritative on that, having ditched M$ long ago...). And if that's the case, I don't know if `access()`, `stat()`, etc. are appropriately defined for non-`char` types, but I would hope they are... Otherwise you need to convert the strings first...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>   //For access
#include <sys/types.h>  //For stat().
#include <sys/stat.h>  //For stat(). 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <direct.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    // make sure we have at least argv[1] and that it is not NULL
    // (shouldn't happen in theory, but paranoia is good sometimes),
    // and that it does not point to an empty string
    if ( (argc < 2) || (argv[1] == NULL) || (*(argv[1]) == '\0') )
      return -1;            // probably should print an error message here

    if ( !access( argv[1], F_OK ) ){

        struct stat status;
        stat( argv[1], &status );

        if ( status.st_mode & S_IFDIR ){
            cout << argv[1] << "can be accessed and is a directory." << endl;  
            getc(stdin);
        }
    }
    else{
        mkdir( "C:\\Program Files\\EZshred\\" );      
        getc( stdin );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried copying and psting your code but I have F_OK is undefined so I couldn't use it  also I fixed the line 929 xstring assertion problem but now I have another one that say access.c line 80 Expression path != null. so how do I fixed that